# Check whether data can be represented in a specified encoding

Tags: java, encoding, character

I'm writing a Java program that saves data to UTF8 text files.  However, I'd also like to provide the option to save to IBM437 for compatibility with an old program that uses the same sort of data files.

How can I check to see if the data the user is trying to save isn't representable in IBM437?  At the moment the file saves without complaining but results in unusual characters being replaced with question marks.

I'd prefer it if I could show a warning to the user that the data they are saving isn't supported in IBM437.  The user could then have the option of manually replacing characters with the nearest ASCII equivalent.

Current code for saving is:

```
String encoding = "UTF-8";
if (forceLegacySupport)
{
    // Force character encoding to IBM437
    encoding = "IBM437";
}

BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(saveFile.getAbsoluteFile()), encoding));
IOController.writeFileToDisk(bw);
bw.close();
```

Comment: What code are you currently using to save the data?

Comment: Charset has a getEncoder() method returning a CharsetEncoder. CharsetEncoder has a canEncode(char) method returning a boolean. The javadoc is sooo helpful.

Comment: My utter and profound apologies @JBNizet for missing that in the javadoc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by JB Nizet in comments you can use charset encoder 
and for creating text/String as UTF-8
just a suggestion from my end:

```
public static char[] cookie = "HEADER_COOKIE".toCharArray();
byte[] cookieInBytes = new byte[COOKIE_SIZE];
for(int i=0;i<cookie.length;i++)
        {
            if(i < cookie.length)
                cookieInBytes[i] = (byte)cookie[i];

        }
String headerStr = new String(cookieInBytes,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: `(byte)cookie[i]` is a very suspicious construction. The whole algorithm makes little sense and seems to work only in the case of the text only containing [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html), which is not implied by the question.

Comment: hi Tom, 
i'm not so much fluent with encodings myself, please let me and the person questioning know a better workaround so that it supports most text. it'll help me in future assignments for sure .
P.s. please don't focus on algorithm specifically this was one solution for me when i was moving data from a Java client to a C based server for empty bytes.

Comment: Java's standard libraries handle conversion to and from its native character encoding, UTF-16 (one of several for the Unicode character set). The question refers to converting to CP437 but since Unicode has more codepoints than CP437 the default conversion substitutes a replacement character ('?') where there is no match. The question asker wants to know when this would happen. `canEncode(charSequence)` does that for Unicode graphemes and `canEncode(char)` does that for UTF-16 code units (presumably you would use the latter for only for a code unit that represents a complete codepoint).